# Changing Domain Extension in android studio package name

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-manifest, manifest.json

This was the package name com.xyz.abc I want to change this to tech.xyz.abc but I was unable to do that

I followed

> Right click on com and selected refract and then Rename

it was then showing me "package contains directories in libraries which cannot be renamed"

Help me out solving this !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

Comment: Hope this will help http://codesfor.in/how-to-rename-package-name-in-android-studio/

Comment: I followed  codesfor.in/how-to-rename-package-name-in-android-studio but it was giving me the error in the Main activity file Can not resolve R